# Limit of the minimum of uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have iid uniform$(0,1)$ random variables $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ and am interested in the limit, as n approaches infinity, of

min$(n{X_{1}, \dots nX_{n}}) = nM$, where M= min$(X_{1}, \dots X_{n})$

My work so far:

$P(nM \leq b) = 1-(1-\frac{b}{n})^{n}$

The limit of $nM$ is, I think, infinity, which is true if $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|nM-0| < {\epsilon})=0$$

This seems to be true, because $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(0 < M < \frac{\epsilon}{n})=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-(1-\frac{\epsilon}{n})^{n})=0$

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

For $b>0$ note that
$$
P(nM \leq b) = 1-(1-\frac{b}{n})^{n}\to1-e^{-b}
$$
as $n\to \infty$. It follows that $nM$ converges in distribution to an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with expected value $1$.

Comment: Why is the limit equal to $1-e^{-b}$? Also, can we say that it converges almost surely, as well?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is one way to define $e^x$. Here $x = -b$. It is possible that the convergence is almost sure, but more work would need to be done to show that.

Comment: @Math1000 More accurately, you define $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$, and use this to prove $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}n)^n$, via $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\tfrac{x}n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\tfrac1{n/x})^{n/x\cdot x}=\lim_{a\to\infty}\big((1+\tfrac1a)^a\big)^x=\big(\lim_{a\to\infty}(1+\tfrac1a)^a\big)^x=e^x$$We use the substitution $a=n/x$, along with other theorems. This works assuming $x\neq 0$, the result for $x=0$ being easy.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I believe defining the exponential function directly as opposed to defining $e$ and then going on to define the exponential function is completely valid.

Comment: @Math1000 Fair enough.

Comment: @Math1000 how would I go about showing the convergence is a.s.?

Comment: Perhaps through the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score 0):

The limit only exists in distribution, not in probability or almost surely. The sequence $nM_n$ is not Cauchy in probability, because adjacent terms do not have a difference which goes in probability to $0$, as shown below:
\begin{align}
P(|nM_n-(n-1)M_{n-1}|>\epsilon)
&\ge P(nM_n>(n-1)+\epsilon)
\\&=P(\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)>\frac{n-1+\epsilon}n)
\\&=1-((n-1+\epsilon)/n)^n
\\&=1-\Big(1-\frac{1}{n/(1-\epsilon)}\Big)^{n/(1-\epsilon)\cdot (1-\epsilon)}
\\&\to 1-e^{1-\epsilon} 
\\&\not\to 0 \tag{for $\epsilon<1$}
\end{align}
To explain the first inequality, note that $(n-1)M_{n-1}\le n-1$ always, so $|nM_n-(n-1)M_{n-1}|>\epsilon$ certainly occurs if $nM_n>(n-1)+\epsilon$.